# Restricting enabled time to a specific time span in UIDatePicker swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm trying to restrict the time of a datePicker from 09:00 AM to 09:00 PM (21:00) with a time interval of 30 minutes. I have tried all known means for that and have been searching the internet for a long time. But I found nothing.
Here is the code I wrote

```
//datePicker.setDate(dateFormatter.date(from: "09.00")!, animated: true)
datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -12, to: dateFormatter.date(from: "21.00")!) //)Calendar.current.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.hour, value: 1, to: Date())
 datePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.hour, value: -12, to: dateFormatter.date(from: "09.00")!)
```

But it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: What is your `datePicker` `datePickerMode`?

Comment: It’s `.time` when I intend to pick time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Restricting user** so she/he can only pick date between 9 and 12 but will show all the available options as this is date picker view's default behaviour but by setting proper **minimumDate** and **maximumDate**  user can only pick between 9 and 21. Try below code and let me know if it works

And if you want to display times of your choice I will suggest better **create an array of times you want to display**, So user will only choose from the array you will provide In this case times between 9 am and 9 pm like [9:00,9:30,10:00,10:30,.....,21:00] and set that array to normal picker

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = .time // setting mode to timer so user can only pick time as you want 
datePicker.minuteInterval = 30  // with interval of 30 
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "HH:mm"

let min = dateFormatter.date(from: "9:00")      //createing min time
let max = dateFormatter.date(from: "21:00") //creating max time
datePicker.minimumDate = min  //setting min time to picker
datePicker.maximumDate = max  //setting max time to picker
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But this made it go reverse. It Mae selection available upto 9:00 AM. I don't know why this happened.

Comment: if you select less than 9 it will set to 9 am and if you will select more that 9 pm it will go back to 9 pm

Comment: https://github.com/Iraniya/datePicker posted here and its working between 9 am to 9 pm check

Comment: I have downloaded it, and it seems to be an empty project. Please check it.

Comment: You founded the answer so removed it, I have updated it you can check

Comment: @Iranya Naynesh It's working. :) Thanks! I'm keeping it.

Answer (score 2):

The values you want to put in `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` are 9am and 9pm of the current date. The current date is what is missing in your code

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let now = Date()  // get the current date and time (2018-03-27 19:38:44)
let components = cal.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: now)  // extract the date components 28, 3, 2018
let today = cal.date(from: components)!  // build another Date value just with date components, without the time (2018-03-27 00:00:00)
datePicker.minimumDate = today.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 9)  // adds 9h
datePicker.maximumDate = today.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 21) // adds 21h
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to achieve this from storyboard?

try following configuration:
[image]

from code:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())
dateComponents.setValue(9, for: .hour)
let minDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
dateComponents.setValue(21, for: .hour)
let maxDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)

self.datePicker?.minimumDate = minDate
self.datePicker?.maximumDate = maxDate
self.datePicker?.minuteInterval = 30
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the output `date` will be in the year 2000

Comment: he only needs time, not date.

Comment: But if you set this `date` to schedule some task, it will never run. You would have to filter the time from the `Date` value

Comment: I am not using a picker from the storyboard. It's an inputView to a textField. Thanks for your comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let now = Date()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
datePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 9, minute: 0, second: 0, of: now)
datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 21, minute: 0, second: 0, of: now)
datePicker.minuteInterval = 30
```

Comment: I tried this. But it makes it revers, i.e., it avails selection of `9:00, 8:30, 8:00...`